# scrlayer-scrpage issue with page numbers

Tags: koma-script, scrlayer-scrpage, scrpage2

I am using the **scrlayer-scrpage** package with Koma **scrlttr2**. Since I replaced scrpage2 with scrlayer-scrpage I have a problem with the formating of page numbers.

I would like to only have the actual # on the page but with my current setting (see below) I get "page #". Can anyone tell me how to get rid of the word "page". Thank you!

```
\documentclass[%
  fontsize=12pt,% 
  version=last,%   
  paper=letterpaper,%%      
  draft=on%       
]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[%
automark,%
nouppercase,%
draft=false%
]{scrlayer-scrpage}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class `scrlttr2` defines `\pagemark` as

```
\newcommand*{%
  \pagemark
}{%
  {\usekomafont{pagenumber}{%
    \pagename\nobreakspace
    \thepage}}}
```

While `scrpage2` overwrites this definition, `scrlayer-scrpage` does not change any existing definition of `\ pagemark`. So you have to redefine `\ pagemark` yourself:

```
\renewcommand*{\pagemark}{{\usekomafont{pagenumber}{\thepage}}}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass[%
  fontsize=12pt,% 
  version=last,%   
  %paper=letterpaper,%% unused global option!!
  draft=on%       
]{scrlttr2}
\renewcommand*{\pagemark}{{\usekomafont{pagenumber}{\thepage}}}

\usepackage[%
  automark,%
  nouppercase,%
  draft=false%
]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Max}
\opening{Hello,}
\lipsum
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```